# How can I use JQuery to post JSON data?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, http-post

I would like to post Json to a web service on the same server. But I don't know how to post Json using JQuery. I have tried with this code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/form/',
    data: {"name":"jonas"},
    success: function(data) { alert('data: ' + data); },
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'json'
});
```

But using this JQuery code the data is not received as Json on the server. This is the expected data at the server: `{"name":"jonas"}` but using JQuery the server receive `name=jonas`. Or in other words, it's "urlencoded" data and not Json.

Is there any way to post the data in Json format instead of urlencoded data using JQuery? Or do I have to use a manual ajax request?

Answer (score 169, accepted):

You're passing an object, *not* a JSON string. When you pass an object, jQuery uses [`$.param`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param) to serialize the object into name-value pairs.

If you pass the data as a string, it won't be serialized:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/form/',
    data: '{"name":"jonas"}', // or JSON.stringify ({name: 'jonas'}),
    success: function(data) { alert('data: ' + data); },
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'json'
});
```

Comment: Please use $.post for that instead of $.ajax.

Comment: @user3746259 Why would you want to use `$.post` for that? It is (a) only a wrapper for `$.ajax` and (b) unable to do what is required here (i.e. the `contentType` property).

Comment: Until, you know, jQuery 3, that is, which is still in the future *now*, never mind when this answer was written *over four years ago*.

Comment: @lonesomeday Thanks. I had the same problem and after converting the object to string, it worked.

Comment: @lonesomeday i had to use your approach even in 3.2 to force contentType to json. *shrug*

Comment: You should probably add `error: function(jqXhr, status, error) { alert(status + ': ' + error);` to the above solution in order to report any issues back to the browser.

Comment: @lafual That's a very bad idea. If you have to log it somewhere, use `console.log`, but browser development tools will give you more useful information without doing anything. The `error` callback should only be used to enable your program to respond to an error.

Comment: It was only an example to show that there could be an error and how it could be displayed. If a user runs the post via an html page, how would you inform them of the issue? For sure, when developing, you can use console.log, but for an end user?

Comment: @lafual That depends entirely what the request was doing. Sometimes it won't be necessary to inform the user. It will, I think, almost *never* be useful to give them the raw Ajax error.

Answer (score 13):

Base on lonesomeday's answer, I create a `jpost` that wraps certain parameters.

```
$.extend({
    jpost: function(url, body) {
        return $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: JSON.stringify(body),
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: 'json'
        });
    }
});
```

Usage:

```
$.jpost('/form/', { name: 'Jonh' }).then(res => {
    console.log(res);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can post data using ajax as :

```
 $.ajax({
   url: "url", 
   type: "POST",
   dataType: "json",
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   data: JSON.stringify({ name: 'value1', email: 'value2' }),
   success: function (result) {
       // when call is sucessfull
    },
    error: function (err) {
    // check the err for error details
    }
 }); // ajax call closing
```

Answer (score -1):

I tried Ninh Pham's solution but it didn't work for me until I tweaked it - see below. Remove contentType and don't encode your json data

```
$.fn.postJSON = function(url, data) {
    return $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: data,
            dataType: 'json'
        });
```

Comment: This will not post a JSON request body

Answer (score -2):

Using `Promise` and checking if the `body` object is a valid JSON. If not a Promise `reject` will be returned.

```
var DoPost = function(url, body) {
    try {
        body = JSON.stringify(body);
    } catch (error) {
        return reject(error);
    }
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: url,
                data: body,
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: 'json'
            })
            .done(function(data) {
                return resolve(data);
            })
            .fail(function(error) {
                console.error(error);
                return reject(error);
            })
            .always(function() {
                // called after done or fail
            });
    });
}
```

Answer (score -2):

The top answer worked fine but I suggest saving your JSON data into a variable before posting it is a little bit cleaner when sending a long form or dealing with large data in general.

```js
var Data = {
"name":"jonsa",
"e-mail":"qwerty@gmail.com",
"phone":1223456789
};


$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/form/',
    data: Data,
    success: function(data) { alert('data: ' + data); },
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'json'
});
```

Comment: You have forgotten to _stringify_ the data