# HTML form is POSTing incorrectly, ignoring jQuery AJAX specifying to format in JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

So the primary problem seems to be that my jQuery code is being completely ignored for some reason.  My form is POSTing data, but it seems to be in regular key-value pairs as opposed to properly formatted JSON.  The issue with what the server is receiving is exactly the same as here:  [How can I use JQuery to post JSON data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255344/how-can-i-use-jquery-to-post-json-data)

My form wasn't POSTing at all until I added the 'action=' and method="POST" to my form section of my HTML, and added a 'name='value to each form input area (textboxes, dropdowns, etc.).  But now that it is posting, it is using the name= 'abc' as the first value in each pair, and the value of the input as second.  I've tried deleting all my jQuery to test this, and it still POSTs exactly the same way, even when there's no jQuery in the code.
Below is my jQuery, designed to POST my four inputs as JSON.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    env1.checked = true;

    $("button").click(function() {
        var x = {
            "apiName": $("#apinameid").val(),
            "apiURL": $("#apiurlid").val(),
            "environment": $("#envid").val(),
            "action": $("#actionid").val()
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://requestb.in/1kynzln1',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            data: x,

            success: function(json) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(json));
            },

            error: function() {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    });

});
```

And here is my HTML (the part which is probably relevant)

```
  <div class="section section-primary"><div class="container"><div class="row"><div class="col-md-12"><h1 class="text-center">Akana Server Proxy Configuration Portal</h1></div></div></div></div>
<div class="section section-warning">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <h3 class="text-left">Please enter your API's information below:</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="section section-warning">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <form action="http://requestb.in/1kynzln1"method="POST"role="form">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="exampleInputEmail1">API Name</label>
            <input name="apiName" class="form-control input-lg" id="apinameid" placeholder="Cat API" type="text">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="exampleInputEmail1">API URL</label>
            <input name="apiURL" class="form-control input-lg" id="apiurlid" placeholder="http://cats.com/api" type="text">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Environment</label>
            <select name="environment" id="envid" class="form-control">
              <option value="Dev" id="devid">Dev</option>
              <option value="Stage" id="stgid">Stage</option>
              <option value="Prod" id="prodid">Prod</option>
            </select>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group"></div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Configuration Action</label>
            <select name="action" id="actionid" class="form-control">
              <option value="Add" id="add">Add a new API</option>
              <option value="Remove" id="remove">Remove an API</option>
            </select>
            <p class="help-block">You can add or remove access to an API by configuring the proxy.</p>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any help is very much appreciated!  Thank you!

Comment: Your button element is a submit button, and your click handler does not cancel the default click behaviour which is to submit the form - so at the moment a "standard" (non-JS) form submission will occur regardless of whether your Ajax code works or not. Note also that if an Ajax error occurs it might be shown in the console, but your `error` handler's `alert(data)` won't work because `data` is not defined.

Comment: How do I prevent the default form submission behavior from occurring?

Comment: The simplest way is to change the button to `<button type="button">` - then a click has no default behaviour. (Note that if you don't specify the `type` attribute at all then it defaults to `type="submit"`.) Or if you add an argument to your click handler to receive the event object you can call `event.preventDefault()` as follows: `$("button").click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); /* your other code here */ });`.

Comment: Unfortunately, neither of these seem to be working.  When I change the button type, it continues to ignore my AJAX, it simply does not post anything at all.  Adding the preventDefault() seems to have no effect, it continues to post incorrectly, and when the two are combined (preventDefault and switching to button type), it again doesn't post.
I have a strong feeling the issue is coming from my formatting or syntax in my jQuery, since Sublime text has been highlighting that script it might mean something is incorrect.

Comment: What is `env1` from the first line of the document ready handler? If that's not defined in an earlier script you'd get a runtime error and the button click handler wouldn't be bound. Are there any errors shown in the console?

Comment: Okay, so I've deleted env1 (that did seem to be a problem).  It is now POSTing closer to how it should be.  I also changed dataType in the AJAX to "jsonp"
The console is now displaying the following error:

uzuoljuz?callback=jQuery2030410…_1470058804961&{"apiName":"ff","apiURL":"44","environm…:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: ok is not defined._______________________The first "uzuolijuz" part is the URL i'm posting to, the {"apiName"..."} stuff is my JSON, and "ok" is the response from the HTTP server.  The callback near the beginning seems to be the problem

Comment: Why did you change it to `jsonp`? Does the service you are posting to support jsonp? (Are you posting to your own server, or some third-party server?)

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer, in `JavaScript` object, you mustn't use quotes as value **key**:

Your code:

```
var x = {
        apiName: $("#apinameid").val(),
        apiURL: $("#apiurlid").val(),
        environment: $("#envid").val(),
        action: $("#actionid").val()
    }
```

Comment: This is not correct. With or without quotes is fine.