# ASP.NET MVC Ajax: refuse to send long string

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, string

I am trying to send long string through Ajax. When the "note" string is short, it goes through fine. When it is more than a thousand characters or so, it silently fails, the action method is not called.

Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("SaveSchoolNote")',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { schoolId: schoolId, note: note },
    cache: false,

    success: function (data) {
    }
});
```

Action:

```
public ActionResult SaveSchoolNote(int schoolId, string note)
{
    ...
}
```

Please help!

Comment: It is most likely due to the MaxJsonLength property. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151987/can-i-set-an-unlimited-length-for-maxjsonlength-in-web-config).

Comment: A thousand characters is not much. Could you try with `data: JSON.stringify({ schoolId: schoolId, note: note }),`?

Comment: combine both properties into an object and post from ajax as a json object

Comment: Set the `contentType` of the ajax properties to `'application/json'`. Right now it's sending it as `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'` which is likely not what you want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use JQuery to post JSON data?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255344/how-can-i-use-jquery-to-post-json-data)