# Pass PHP Array to script through jquery $.ajax() in Wordpress

Tags: arrays, json, ajax, wordpress

I have a big array() in DOM.

```
<div id="array"><?php echo serialize($bigArray); ?></div>
```

I need to pass this data through ajax in my wordpress theme.

```
$(document).on('click','#somewhere',function(){
        var datas = $('#array').html();
        $.ajax({
            url : ajax_object.ajaxurl,
            type : 'post',
            data : {
                action:'wordpress_action',
                array: datas
            },
            success: function(res) {
                console.log(res);
            }
        });
    })
```

And in my php script:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_wordpress_hook', 'my_func');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_wordpress_hook', 'my_func');

function my_func(){
    $data = unserialize($_POST['array']);
    print_r($data);
    die();
}
```

But this seems not working.

Any suggestion?
How can I pass php array through ajax?
json_encode? php session?

Comment: I changed my post. I have wrong to write it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the server you should embed your `$bigArray` in JSON format into an [HTML data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes).

PHP's JSON-encoding function is called `json_encode()` (not `serialize()`, which does [something entirely different](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)).

```php
<div id="array" data-entities="<?php htmlspecialchars(json_encode($bigArray)) ?>">
  ... regular HTML here ...
</div>
```

You **always** need to call `htmlspecialchars()` when you write data to HTML.

---

On the client you can access the data attribute with jQuery's `.data()` method.

For transport via HTTP you need to re-encode the data as JSON. Javascript's JSON-encoding function is called `JSON.stringify()`. See: [How can I use JQuery to post JSON data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255344/how-can-i-use-jquery-to-post-json-data-)

```
$(document).on('click', '#somewhere', function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: ajax_object.ajaxurl,
        type: 'post',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify({
            action: 'wordpress_action',
            array: $('#array').data('entities')
        })
    }).done(function (res) {
        console.log(res);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">\n";
echo "var strJson = " . json_encode($bigArray) . "\n";
echo "var arrAsObj = JSON.parse(strJson)\n";
echo "</script>\n";
```

now you should have access to these two variables on the page. You should be able to pass 'arrAsObj' in the request body of your ajax post. If you have trouble make sure that this script is placed BEFORE the ajax call in the html file.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Tomalak, with your suggestion I solved my error, but I edited your code.

```
<div id="array" data-value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($bigArray)) ?>">

$(document).on('click','#somewhere',function(){
        var datas = $('#array').data('value');
        $.ajax({
            url : ajax_object.ajaxurl,
            type : 'post',
            data : {
                action:'wordpress_action',
                array: datas
            },
            success: function(res) {
                console.log(res);
            }
        });
    })
```

Then in PHP script:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_wordpress_hook', 'my_func');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_wordpress_hook', 'my_func');

function my_func(){
    $data = $_POST['array'];
    print_r($data);
    die();
}
```

This works like I expected