# serialize() form showing internal server error

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

I have a form, I am using serialize() to get the values from the form and post it in ajax. But I am getting internal server error. Below I have attached the code

```
var formData = $('#loginForm').serialize();
var request = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Ajax/Register",
    data: formData,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
});
```

The formData produces username=aaa&password=bbb. I found that formData is the problem. If I use `data : '{"username":"aaa","password":"bbb"}'` it is working. Now I have to parse the data through hard coding it. is there any method that does this or resolves this issue?? and also If I change `type:GET` it works. but that's not the right way.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255344/how-can-i-use-jquery-to-post-json-data

Comment: Possible Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162749/convert-js-object-to-json-string

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert form data to JavaScript object with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/convert-form-data-to-javascript-object-with-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply use [serializeArray](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) instead of .serialize();

```
function objectifyForm(formArray) {//serialize data function

  var returnArray = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < formArray.length; i++){
    returnArray[formArray[i]['name']] = formArray[i]['value'];
  }
  return returnArray;
}

var formData = objectifyForm($('#loginForm').serializeArray());

var request = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Ajax/Register",
    data: JSON.stringify(formData),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
});
```

This is probably a duplicate of :
[Convert form data to JavaScript object with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/convert-form-data-to-javascript-object-with-jquery)

Comment: yes, I tried serializeArray() too.. still same problem

Comment: This still won't send json without 1 more step. (you forgot to stringify)

Comment: So convert the resulting array back to a serialized object

Answer (score -1):

`serialize()` returns a URL-encoded string. If you really need JSON, you'll need to create the object by hand and call `JSON.stringify()`.

```
var formData = JSON.stringify({
    username: $("#loginForm input[name=username]").val(),
    password: $("#loginForm input[name=password]").val()
});
```

For a more automated method, see [Serialize form data to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11338774/serialize-form-data-to-json)

If the server script supports ordinary form data, you could use `serialize()` and remove the `contentType:` option.

Comment: I am have another registration form where I have 10 more fields. So I was trying to make it simple(if it is even possible) instead of using .val() for every fields..

Comment: Unfortunately, jQuery doesn't have a shortcut for creating JSON from a form. Most servers expect URL-encoded parameters.

Comment: It does however have a shortcut to create an array, and the browser has a, uh "shortcut" for converting an array to json... i mean..

Comment: @KevinB But the server wants a JSON object, not a JSON array. I assume you're talking about `.serializeArray()`.

Answer (score -1):

`serialize()` does not create an object with your form data, it creates a string. Maybe you want to use the [post](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) method instead:

```
var formData = $('#loginForm').serialize();
var request = $.post(
    "/Ajax/Register",
    formData
);
```