# Cannot read NULL variable in PHP after posting JSON array through .ajax()

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, jsonencoder

I'm having a problem like many other people, being able to read a PHP array variable after having sent it through ajax() post.  Ajax is succeeding and displaying the returned data, which is NULL.  I have already thoroughly researched SO solutions for this JSON/PHP problem, and my problem description shows 'almost' EVERY solution on SO so far.

On the PHP side I've tried:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
var_dump($data);
```

(Skipping over $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA (deprecated) because it's equal to file_get_contents('php://input')

and also:

```
$data = json_decode($_POST["a_arr"], true);
```

I've already tried clearing the UTF-8 BOM with the sed command

```
sed '1s/^\xEF\xBB\xBF//' < index.html > index2.html
```

My .ajax() looks like this:

```
$.ajax ({
    url:"file.php",
    method:"post",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: { a_arr : JSON.stringify(arr) },
    })
    .done(function(response){
        $("#status").html(response);
    });
```

On the Javascript side here is my array:

```
var arr = [{"name":_name, "phone":_phone, "email":_email, "repname":repname, "repnumber":repnumber, "office":office}];
ajax_post(arr);
```

I've checked to make sure there is no JSON formatting error, the following successfully shows me a valid JSON formatted array:

```
var data_arr = JSON.stringify(arr);
document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = data_arr;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use JQuery to post JSON data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255344/how-can-i-use-jquery-to-post-json-data)

Comment: I have thoroughly reviewed SO for similar JSON/PHP cases, and though while close in appearance, I have found no solution as my problem description illustrates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change to:

```
data: JSON.stringify(arr),
```

When you give an object to the `data:` option, it converts it to URL-encoded format, not JSON.

Or you can leave the `data:` option as it is, but get rid of the `contentType:` option, and then you should use

```
$data = json_decode($_POST['a_arr'], true);
```

Comment: Very grateful for the input and information!  Ok, I tried your suggesttion, relying on data: to push URL encoding, I removed the name and put:
    data: JSON.stringify(arr),
This also returns NULL!

Then I put the data: element back to JSON format:
    data: { a_arr : JSON.stringify(arr) },

Commented out the contentType:
    //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

And lastly switched from php://input over to:
    $data = json_decode($_POST['a_arr'], true);
$var_dump($data); is still NULL in both cases :(

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? The `method:` option was added in 1.9.0, before that it was `type:`.

Comment: What do you see in `var_dump(file_get_contents("php://input"));`?

Comment: Using:  jquery-1.8.3.min.js

Comment: Wow, nice suggestion: the return data is:  string(0) ""   Which is funny because I get a valid javascript JSON string pre .ajax()

Comment: Based on your question, I shot up to Jquery 1.12.4.min.js and I immediately got a valid string(256) response.  I'm concurrently learning JSON and working with other existing Jquery projects on this web app.  When I had tried upgrading to Jquery 3.3.1 it had broken functionality.  Thank You!